# Why does MathOverflow keep logging me out?

Tags: support, user-interface, user-accounts, login

I'm getting tired of logging in to MathOverflow ten times a day. The other Stack Exchange sites I use keep me logged in, and so did MathOverflow until recently. What is different about MathOverflow? Is there anything I can do about it?

**P.S.** The funny thing is, when I'm logged in to math.SE (which is most all the time), I get notifications of reputation changes, responses, etc. on MO, but I still don't get logged in to MO automatically, I have to type in my email address and password.

Comment: You might want to include some detail on your setup (login-method, browser, OS) and what exactly happens. For me MO does not behave any differently from the several other SE sites I use (that is it does not log me out for random reasons except once in a blue moon maybe), and I do not think there is anything particularly different on MO as regards login. You could try (if you did not yet) to clean cache and see if it solves the thing.

Comment: I had similar issues with both MO and MSE recently. On my Nexus phone and Windows 8.1 (32bit) tablet. Both issues stopped after sufficiently many attempts to clear cookies and clean up the cache. I couldn't pinpoint either the reason for the problem or the reason for it to solve itself.

Comment: @quid I use Windows 7 with Internet Explorer, and I log in with my email address and Stack Exchange password. I can't recall the last time I ever got logged out of my other SE sites: math.se, chess.se, english.se, or scifi.se. (The scifi site for some reason I log into with gmail, that doesn't seem to make any difference.) For a long time MathOverflow acted the same way. A few weeks ago something happened and MO started logging me out unpredictably, at least I haven't found a pattern. Dunno about this cache-cleaning business. Cleared 1 cache, deleted temp files, maybe it helped some, not sure.

Comment: As [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2018/7/4), the sites with their own domains (such as stackoverflow, superuser) behave differently. (At least according to the linked post - I do not know whether the information is up to date.) Have you tried Todd Trimbles suggestion from the other post - to see what happens if you use other browser?