# Why is log-in hidden

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, login

On the front page I looked in vain for "log in" button. Eventually found to my surprise that clicking on "sign up" takes me to a page where I can choose between "sign up" and "log in". Do I have any reason to complain, or do I have only myself to blame? If I were more computer-savvy, I would have known that "sign up" includes "log in"?

I use the feature-request tag because I am requesting a more visible log-in button. It would be even better if MO would **keep me logged in** the way other stack exchange sites do.

Comment: I will add link to your previous post: [Why does MathOverflow keep logging me out?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2295) (In case somebody has an advice regarding the issue you mentioned in the second paragraph.)

Comment: What happens if you change your browser? In the post Martin linked to, you were using Internet Explorer; could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't managed to reproduce the effect you're describing.

I'm not computer-savvy either, but this is what I see when I go to MathOverflow in a window where the history doesn't show I'm already logged in (e.g., a private window). In the menu up at the top there's a Log In button, next to Sign Up. Here I'm using FireFox 60.0.2.

(If I'm already logged in and open a new tab in the same window and go to MO, I'm automatically logged in at the new tab.)

[image]

Comment: I see two "sign up" buttons in your screen shot: a black on gray button over on the left side, and a white on blue button in the upper right. You say there is a "log in" button next to the latter? Left or right side? I don't see it. Of course I do have some vision problems.

Comment: @bof It is just to the left of the blue one. It is dark blue text on black, and I agree that it is not very visible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Aha! Thanks!

Comment: @bof If you pass your cursor over the screen shot, can you then click to enlarge the image?  I can, but I want to make sure others can too.

Comment: OK. Sometimes I can see it. Thanks. My "feature request" stands: I request the management to use more contrasting colors, for the sake of the visually challenged.

Comment: @bof I suppose that when the new theme comes to MO (which is probably soon), the MathOverflow mods can talk with the SE staff also about various design-related feature requests. Relevant post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365).